# Optimization of find and Replace Script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, awk

I developed a script which parse texts and on specific condition it replace text and generate new file.

I would like to know if i can optimize it or any alternative suggetions

```
cat *inputparams.txt   | awk -F"|" 'BEGIN {OFS=","} $2==1&&$3==1{$3="Subscription Creation without Previous"} $2==1&&$3==5{$3="Offer Upgrade"} $2==1&&$3==6{$3="Offer Downgrade"} $2==1&&$3==7{$3="Campaign Extend"} $2==1&&$3==8{$3="Campaign Change"} $2==1&&$3==27{$3="Subscription Update"} $2==2&&$3==2{$3="Charging Renewal"} $2==2&&$3==3{$3="Subscription Reactivation"} $2==2&&$3==4{$3="Subscription Reactivation with Recharge Monitoring"} $2==2&&$3==8 {$3="Campaign Change" } $2==2&&$3==30 {$3="Limited Service"}  $2==3&&$3==11{$3="Cancellation"} $2==3&&$3==17{$3="Subscriber Account Reactivation"} $2==4&&$3==11{$3="Cancellation"} $2==5&&$3==11{$3="Cancellation"} $2==5&&$3==12{$3="Expiration"} $2==5&&$3==13{$3="Inactivation due to Charging"} $2==5&&$3==14{$3="Inactivation due to Ceased Account"} $2==5&&$3==15 {$3="Inactivation due to Payment Method Change"} $2==5&&$3==16 {$3="Inactivation due to Ownership Change"} $2==5&&$3==18 {$3="Inactivation due to Offer Upgrade"} $2==5&&$3==19  {$3="Inactivation due to Offer Downgrade" } $2==6&&$3==9{$3="Campaign Schedule"} $2==6&&$3==10{$3="Offer Schedule"}  $1==5 && $2==2{$2="RENEWAL"} $1==4 && $2==2{$2="SUBS. CREATE RENEWAL AOC"} $1==6 && $2==3{$2="REFUND"} $1==4 && $2==5 {$2="INACTIVATION"} $1==5 && $2==4{$2="PENALTY"} $1==1{$1="RESERVE"} $1==2{$1="COMMIT"} $1==3{$1="ROLLBACK"} $1==5 && $2==1{$2="SUBS. CREATE DIRECT DEBIT"}  $2==1 {$2="CREATION"}  {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$8}' >  $RECON_PATH/tx_id.txt

cat *inputparams.txt |  awk -F"[" '{print $4}' | awk -F"]" '{print $1}' | awk -F","  'BEGIN {OFS=","} $2==1{$2="POSTPAID"} $2==2{$2="PREPAID"} {print $2,$1}' > $RECON_PATH/msisdn_payment

cat *inputparams.txt |  awk -F"," '{print $3 }' > $RECON_PATH/package

paste -d","  $RECON_PATH/tx_id.txt $RECON_PATH/package  $RECON_PATH/msisdn_payment  > $RECON_PATH/final.txt
```

Following is sample record

```
5|2|3|rfe-29883066|9840311190936312183|2.0|49.0|20131119093631|[[],4900671,SOCIAL_DATA,null,SOCIAL DATA,20130710000000,,,[971508592346,2],null,7012183,20130926190549,[[{LIMITED_PERIOD_END_DATE=20131110093613}{INITIAL_CHARGED_AMOUNT=49.0}{INITIAL_CHARGE_OPTION=1}{ENE_EVENT_ID=24645862}{FULFILL_ON_RESERVE=0}],false,false,null,4900672,SOCIAL DATA,20130710000000,2,20131119093631,0,2,[111111111111,2],USSD,2592000000,[{[{PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_NORMAL_QOS=2000002935}{PREFERRED_PACKAGE_ID=PACKAGE_ID_AUTO_RN}{PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_WITH_THROTTLING=2000002935}{PACKAGE_ID_AUTO_RN=2000002881}{PROVISIONED_PACK_ID=2000002935}{PROVISIONED_PACK_TYPE=PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_WITH_THROTTLING}],DATAN_SOCIAL_DATA,4900667,DATAN,DATAN,[]}{[{PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_NORMAL_QOS=2000002922}{PREFERRED_PACKAGE_ID=PACKAGE_ID_AUTO_RN}{PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_WITH_THROTTLING=2000002922}{PACKAGE_ID_AUTO_RN=2000002880}{PROVISIONED_PACK_ID=2000002922}{PROVISIONED_PACK_TYPE=PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_WITH_THROTTLING}],DATAN_DATA_SOCIAL,4900669,DATAN,DATAN,[]}{[{PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_NORMAL_QOS=2000003031}{PREFERRED_PACKAGE_ID=PACKAGE_ID_AUTO_RN}{PACKAGE_ID_ONE_TIME_WITH_THROTTLING=2000003031}{PACKAGE_ID_AUTO_RN=2000003030}],DATAN_SOCIAL_THROTT,5400425,DATAN,DATAN,[]}{[{RATE_PLAN_ID=629120}],MKTWSSOCIALDATA,4900665,CMN,CMN,[]}],2,null,6912967,20130926190549]]
```

Regards

Comment: Please add some example data.  Looks to me like you're just reformatting the `*inputparams.txt` data in 4 passes of the data (including the `paste` call) where `awk` would let you do this in one pass including the final output.  Personally, I'd make an awk executable script (ex. [awk_example1.awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Scripts) [from here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-2)) where the BEGIN would have an associate array with string keys you could construct for lookups like: `arr["2:1 3:5"] = "Offer Upgrade"` and some helper functions for creating keys, and the final output.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan, if you want to improve permanence, you ought to avoid spawning new processes with `|`. Meaning you should write a proper awk script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
awk -F"|" -f parse.awk *inputparams.txt
```

where `parse.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS=","
} 
{
    getFields()
    split($0,a,"[");
    split(a[4],b,"]");
    split(b[1],c,",");
    if (c[2]==1) msi="POSTPAID"
    else if (c[2]==2) msi="PREPAID"
    msi=msi","c[1]
    split($0,d,",")
    pack=d[3]
    print f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f8,pack,msi
}

function getFields() {
    f1=$1; f2=$2; f3=$3; f4=$4; f5=$5; f8=$8
    if ($2==1) {
        if ($3==1) {
            f3="Subscription Creation without Previous"
        } 
        if ($3==5) {
            f3="Offer Upgrade"
        } 
        if ($3==6) {
            f3="Offer Downgrade"
        } 
        if ($3==7) {
            f3="Campaign Extend"
        } 
        if ($3==8) {
            f3="Campaign Change"
        } 
        if ($3==27) {
            f3="Subscription Update"
        } 
    }
    if ($2==2) {
        if ($3==2) {
            f3="Charging Renewal"
        } 
        if ($3==3) {
            f3="Subscription Reactivation"
        } 
        if ($3==4) {
            f3="Subscription Reactivation with Recharge Monitoring"
        } 
        if ($3==8) {
            f3="Campaign Change" 
        } 
        if ($3==30) {
            f3="Limited Service"
        } 
    } 
    if ($2==3) {
        if ($3==11) {
            f3="Cancellation"
        }
        if ($3==17) {
            f3="Subscriber Account Reactivation"
        }
    } 
    if ($2==4) {
        if ($3==11) {
            f3="Cancellation"
        }
    }
    if ($2==5) {
        if ($3==11) {
            f3="Cancellation"
        } 
        if ($3==12) {
            f3="Expiration"
        } 
        if ($3==13) {
            f3="Inactivation due to Charging"
        }
        if ($3==14) {
            f3="Inactivation due to Ceased Account"
        } 
        if ($3==15) {
            f3="Inactivation due to Payment Method Change"
        } 
        if ($3==16) {
            f3="Inactivation due to Ownership Change"
        } 
        if ($3==18) {
            f3="Inactivation due to Offer Upgrade"
        } 
        if ($3==19)  {
            f3="Inactivation due to Offer Downgrade" 
        } 
    }
    if ($2==6) {
        if ($3==9) {
            f3="Campaign Schedule"
        } 
        if ($3==10) {
            f3="Offer Schedule"
        }
    }  
    if ($1==5 && $2==2) {
        f2="RENEWAL"
    } 
    if ($1==4 && $2==2) {
        f2="SUBS. CREATE RENEWAL AOC"
    } 
    if ($1==6 && $2==3) {
        f2="REFUND"
    } 
    if ($1==4 && $2==5) {
        f2="INACTIVATION"
    } 
    if ($1==5 && $2==4) {
        f2="PENALTY"
    } 
    if ($1==5 && $2==1) {
        f2="SUBS. CREATE DIRECT DEBIT"
    } 
    if ($2==1) {
        f2="CREATION"
    }
    if ($1==1) {
        f1="RESERVE"
    } 
    if ($1==2) {
        f1="COMMIT"
    } 
    if ($1==3) {
        f1="ROLLBACK"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the cat and you'll have it. You can do `awk -F"|" -f parse.awk *inputparams.txt` and save yourself a process.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I was thinking.  Put the script into a file and make it executable so it can be run like:

```
script.awk *inputparams.txt
```

The script:
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f

```
BEGIN {
    FS="|"
    OFS="," 

    # $3 field strings
    arr[ "2==1 3==1" ] = "Subscription Creation without Previous"
    arr[ "2==1 3==5" ] = "Offer Upgrade"
    arr[ "2==1 3==6" ] = "Offer Downgrade"
    arr[ "2==1 3==7" ] = "Campaign Extend"
    arr[ "2==1 3==8" ] = "Campaign Change"
    arr[ "2==1 3==27" ] = "Subscription Update"
    arr[ "2==2 3==2" ] = "Charging Renewal"
    arr[ "2==2 3==3" ] = "Subscription Reactivation"
    arr[ "2==2 3==4" ] = "Subscription Reactivation with Recharge Monitoring"
    arr[ "2==2 3==8" ] = "Campaign Change"
    arr[ "2==2 3==30" ] = "Limited Service"
    arr[ "2==3 3==11" ] = "Cancellation"
    arr[ "2==3 3==17" ] = "Subscriber Account Reactivation"
    arr[ "2==4 3==11" ] = "Cancellation"
    arr[ "2==5 3==11" ] = "Cancellation"
    arr[ "2==5 3==12" ] = "Expiration"
    arr[ "2==5 3==13" ] = "Inactivation due to Charging"
    arr[ "2==5 3==14" ] = "Inactivation due to Ceased Account"
    arr[ "2==5 3==15" ] = "Inactivation due to Payment Method Change"
    arr[ "2==5 3==16" ] = "Inactivation due to Ownership Change"
    arr[ "2==5 3==18" ] = "Inactivation due to Offer Upgrade"
    arr[ "2==5 3==19" ] = "Inactivation due to Offer Downgrade"
    arr[ "2==6 3==9" ] = "Campaign Schedule" 
    arr[ "2==6 3==10" ] = "Offer Schedule"

    # $2 field strings
    arr[ "1==5 2==2" ] = "RENEWAL"
    arr[ "1==4 2==2" ] = "SUBS. CREATE RENEWAL AOC"
    arr[ "1==6 2==3" ] = "REFUND"
    arr[ "1==4 2==5" ] = "INACTIVATION"
    arr[ "1==5 2==4" ] = "PENALTY"
    arr[ "1==5 2==1" ] = "SUBS. CREATE DIRECT DEBIT"
    arr[ "0==0 2==1" ] = "CREATION" # this needs special attention

    # $1 field strings
    arr[ "0==0 1==1" ] = "RESERVE"
    arr[ "0==0 1==2" ] = "COMMIT"
    arr[ "0==0 1==3" ] = "ROLLBACK"

    # $9 field, subfield 10 (by comma) strings - a key name "hack"
    arr[ "9==10 2==1" ] = "POSTPAID"
    arr[ "9==10 2==2" ] = "PREPAID"
}

# print output line here
{
    print getString(0,1),getStringWithDefault(1,2),getString(2,3),$4,$5,$8,field9Strings()
}

function makeShortKey( field, value ) {
    gsub( value, "", " " )
    return field "==" value
}

function makeLongKey( f1, v1, f2, v2 ) {
    return makeShortKey( f1, v1 ) " " makeShortKey( f2, v2 )
}

function getStringWithDefault( a, b ) {
    sd = getString( a, b )
    if( s == "" ) sd = getString( 0, b )
    return sd
}

# take fields and their values to construct keys - 0 is special to 'standardize' keys
function getString( field1, field2 ) {
    s = arr[ makeLongKey( field1, field1 == 0 ? 0 : $field1, field2, $field2 ) ]
    return (s == "") ? $field2 : s
}

function field9Strings() {
    split( $9, carr, "," )
    sub( /\[/, "", carr[ 9 ] );
    sub( /]/, "", carr[ 10 ])
    s9 = arr[ "9==10 " makeShortKey( 2, carr[ 10 ] ) ]
    return carr[ 3 ] OFS ((s9 == "") ? carr[ 10 ] : s9) OFS carr[ 9 ]
}
```

I've chosen to use the `arr` because I think it makes the strings more maintainable.  I've tried to chose keys that would make it possible to read in those strings from an string file in another revision.

The keys for field 9 parsing are "hard-coded" right now.

For `arr[ "0==0 2==1" ]` I ended up adding a special `getStringWithDefault()` function.  If "CREATION" depended on a value from column 1, the key could be updated and that function could be removed.

Comment: +1 Interesting use of associative arrays.. Maybe they also could have been read from a text file (using a concise format)..